# Sort Numbers with a Letter Suffix from an Access Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, regex, database, ms-access

I am attempting to retrieve some information from an Access database using an `OleDbConnection`. I am trying to Order the results By a column that contains a set of numbers in string format.

I wanted the results in a natural order (e.g. 1, 2, 10, 20 versus 1, 10, 2, 20), so I converted the data in the column of interest to integers and sorted the results.

```
"SELECT Drawing, Sheet FROM TableName ORDER BY CINT(Sheet) ASC"
```

This works fine, except in some cases when the table data has values with a letter suffix (e.g. 1A, 2B, etc...). The command above obviously fails for theses cases.

I would like the results sorted like so: 1, 2, 2A, 2B, 3, 3A, and so on...

So, how to go about this? I've seen some examples that use `REGEXP` and some conditional statements, but apparently MS SQL doesn't support `REGEXP`. So I'm stuck. Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use a regular expression in a query run from outside an Access session.  If the query is run inside an Access session, it could use a custom VBA function with `RegExp`.  But a regular expression approach seems like over-kill for this situation anyway.  You can get what you need simply with `Val()`.

The [Val Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx) will return a number from the digits in your string.  It will stop reading the string when it hits a letter.

Here's an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
? Val("2A")
 2
```

Use it in your query like this ...

```swl
SELECT Drawing, Sheet
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Val(Sheet), Sheet;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I noticed it was necessary to ORDER BY Val(Sheet) and Sheet, otherwise only the preceding numbers would be in natural order.

Comment: OK, sounds like you noticed that before I thought to include it in the answer.  That was a head smacker.  :-)